# The mean of the compound Poisson process

Tags: poisson-distribution, uniform-distribution, poisson-process

I have a compound Poisson process with uniform distribution. The Poisson arrival rate is $=\lambda$ and uniform distribution is defined over $[0,a]$. What will be the mean of this compound Poisson process with uniform distribution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use conditional expectation.

Suppose
$$
Y_t=\sum_{j=1}^{N_t}U_i,
$$
where $N_t$ is a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$, and each $U_j\sim\text{Unif}(\left[0,a\right])$. Here we suppose that $\left\{U_j\right\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is an independent sequence of random variables, and that it is independent from the process $N_t$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}Y_t&=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left(Y_t|N_t\right)\right)\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{N_t}U_i\Bigg|N_t\right)\right)\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{N_t}\mathbb{E}\left(U_j|N_t\right)\right)\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{N_t}\mathbb{E}U_j\right)\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{N_t}\frac{a}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac{a}{2}\mathbb{E}N_t\\
&=\frac{a}{2}\lambda t.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think your last line should be $\frac{a}{2}\lambda$ instead of $\frac{a}{2}\lambda t$. Right?

Comment: @FrankMoses: My pleasure. Not exactly, because $N_t$ is a Poisson process here. Poisson process means that $N_{t+1}-N_t$ follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$. But as you consider $N_t$ as a whole, its a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$. But I need to correct my statement that $N_t\sim\text{Poiss}(\lambda)$; this is truly confusing.

Comment: @FrankMoses: I just corrected the statements. You may find them in the third and the fourth line.

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand your first comment. What is the value of $t$ in your answer? Should it not be as a subscript like $\lambda_t$?

Comment: @FrankMoses: $t$ means time. $N_t$ means a (time-dependent) [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Interpreted_as_a_counting_process). $\lambda$ is a fixed parameter, independent from $t$.

Comment: Ok I understand it now. Thank you so much Hypernova

Comment: @FrankMoses: My pleasure :-)